# How to read data line by line using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code which give me the data in Example.html file. But I have to read the data line by line

```
html_doc = open("Example.html","r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: Can you please add your expected output??

Comment: Assume the below is the text present in HTML file  

A thirsty crow flew into a village in search of water.
The crow flew over the houses, fields, and trees.
The crow put his beak inside the pitcher but could not reach the water.
The water level was too low, and the narrow opening prevented his neck from going all the way down     

Expected Output :

  I have to read first line first than i have to compare if first line contains word "prevented" or not. If it contains do something if not read next line and compare. Comparing i can do but i dont know how to read the text line by line.

Comment: What does "line" mean, in a HTML file? Physical lines, which are separated by a `\n`? Separate `<p>` contents? Text lines as they are broken by your browser, with your current font and size, in your current local browser window?

Comment: lines separated by </A>

Answer (score 5):

You can easily read data line by line with splitlines() method.

For your case you can use:

```
html_doc = open("Example.html","r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
output = soup.get_text()

for row in output.splitlines():
  # Do whatever you want
```

**EDIT :** For your request which is reading 20 lines after an if condition, you can *enumerate* the *splitlines()* method and read the just next 20 lines. Then, exit from the for loop with *break* statement.

```
for idx, row in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    if row == "ADD.c":
       twenty_line = idx + 20
    try:
       if idx < twenty_line:
          print(row + "\n")
       else:
          break
    except NameError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: This work for me but if i have a condition like                for row in output.splitlines():             if row == "ADD.c":        now if the row is equals to ADD.c than read the just next 20 lines             How we can do that?

Comment: I have edited the answer according to your comment. @RakeshSharma